# Triggering cloud watch event at a particular time

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a lambda function also have created the cloud watch event in every day. Now I want to trigger this function at every day 10 o clock indian time morning How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already checked, here are the instructions from AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html